# MySQL TEXT entry does not match with html textbox

Tags: html, mysql, sql

In my website I give users a unique certification code based on a combination of their first and last names. For example: ŠôË¨ÒxèÕñZÉ¬.åŠ ¦$ø¨R³ÇtzÒÁ{Ú. However when you paste that into the textbox where the certification code is prompted, it doesn't match with the SQL entry. I made a page that displays the sql table's contents. Why doesn't it work?

```
$certification = $_GET["Certification"];
$firstname = $_GET["Firstname"];
$information = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM SCstudents WHERE Firstname = '$firstname'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($information);
$cert = $row['Certification'];

if ($cert == $certification)

{
...signup code...
}
```

I always get that $cert !== $certification. Even when i input the correct code into the textbox.

Comment: Probably character set encoding issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8")
```

before any other query.

And in your html head tag which displays the data add:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything. I can echo the sql table value in the html page and it is identical to the text put on the textbox. For some reason they don't match.

Comment: ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Comment: Btw whats the language you use on the website?Choose a collation based on that language.